# How can i find where a method or a variable is used in Android Studio (shortcut)

Tags: java, android, windows-7, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to find the source by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + left click on a method, for example, but what if I want to find where this method is used? I'm using Windows 7.

Let's suppose I have the following method:

```
class A {
    public int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

and I am using this method in

```
class B {
    ...
    a.sum(c, d);
    ...
}
```

and I want to find where I used `sum` while I was in class `A`.

PS: I'm new to Android studio (started using it about a month ago).

Comment: Not sure but I think you can control click on the variable.

Comment: control + click find the declaration not where is it used :(

Comment: In android studio 1.1.0 on linux , alt-F7 is apparently doing what you seek to accomplish, what is your version of android studio

Comment: alt f7 worked ! thanks !

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In Android Studio, highlight the method and either right click > Find usages or use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> shortcut.

Edit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd> on a method is useful for finding where that method was initially declared

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu users:

For me <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> has not worked,
so I've solved the conflict by going to the

```
Ubuntu System settings-> keyboard -> shortcuts
```

and changing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in there with another combination.

And now it's working ))

Answer (score 3):

Just click on the method or variable and any usages will be highlighted and on the scroll bar on the right side of your code you will see gray bars appear, those are the usages of the current highlighted (or clicked on) variable or method within your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here are different key shortcuts for displaying method or variable usage. The keymaps with <kbd>F14</kbd> in them were added by me; the others are default. For Windows (and Linux?), replace the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (I think). Find Usages shows them in a dedicated window in Android Studio (the solution in other answers), while Show Usages puts them in a popup (second image below).

[image: My Android Studio preferences]

[image: Usage popup (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>]

Answer (score 2):

To find all uses of a variable or method in Android Studio you can use

1. ctrl+shift+F7(window/Ubuntu)
2. after that for navigation purpose you can use F3

Answer (score 0):

use [Ctrl+b]  or  [Ctrl+Alt+b] to navigate to the origin of the method or variable declearation and implementation

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is `Ctrl+Alt+7` or `Ctrl+b` to show the usage of the class. `Ctrl+Alt+F7` is not work.