# What is the hotkey to navigate back to the line where a method is used?

Tags: android-studio

When I left click the method in Android Studio with control button

```
_setInterval(_sliderValue);
```

it opens the method definition

```
Future<void> _setInterval(double foo) async {
    ...
    print('interval saved');
}
```

Now, what is the *hotkey* to navigate back to the line where the method is used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can press ALT + F7 to see the method usage.
Or right click on the method and you will see a menu with the Find usage option.

Shortcut from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000308/how-can-i-find-where-a-method-or-a-variable-is-used-in-android-studio-shortcut)

Also, there is an option called Inlay hints that displays a few useful tips like usages, inheritors, problems
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, to navigate back to the line where the method is using - use **Ctrl+B** shortcut or control click the method definition name.